# Difference between quantiles

Tags: quantiles, pandas

As far as I understood from its definition, quantile borders should divide a dataset into equal parts (or at least into almost equal parts, if the dataset doesn't have enough entries or has an odd number of elements). I used `pandas` function `quantile` to get quartiles from my dataset:

```
tquantiles = rawData['t'].quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75])
```

Output shows quantile border values:

```
0.25    -3.1
0.50     6.7
0.75    15.6
Name: t, dtype: float64
```

`rawData` is a result of a SQL query:

```
rawData = sqlio.read_sql_query('SELECT * ' +
'FROM cards ' +
'INNER JOIN weather ' +
'on ceil_time_3h(event_date) = weather.datetime', conn)
```

So, assuming that quantiles are equal, I try to compare the amount of objects between named values:

```
SELECT count("t") AS "25" FROM cards
INNER JOIN weather
on ceil_time_3h(event_date) = weather.datetime
WHERE t >= 15.6;
```

This is for the top 25%. Changing values, I selected quartiles, including the left border. Those values are not equal: 128829, 130150, 130250, 130266 for below 25%, 50%, 75% and above 75% respectively. Moreover, the sum of those counts is less than the number of elements in the dataset.

How do the quantiles differ from each other in my case? Why does the sum differ from the number of elements in the dataset?

Comment: Why don't you use the window function `NTILE` directly? Anyway, I think this question is off-topic per our [FAQ](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Are you sure that your code is doing what you think it is? One way to check would be to try in another piece of software. For example, you could try this in R, or in Excel (assuming you are running a recent enough version that can cope with the number of rows!). Are your values of 't' integers?

Comment: It would be interesting to compare the result of your query for `WHERE t >= 15.6` to the result of the query `WHERE t > 15.6`: how do those two counts differ?

Comment: It seems that your data are measured with resolution 0.1 and that the range is at least 18.7. My guess given the mention of "weather": Celsius temperatures.  Let's guess range 50: the tails beyond the quartiles are often longer than the difference between the quartiles.. That means of the order of 500 distinct values. It seems that your sample size is of the order of 500000, so on average each distinct value occurs about 1000 times, and ties are everywhere. It's also entirely possible that your data are quirkier than that if human readings are involved. Ties are likely to be the issue.

Comment: @NickCox you're absolutely right, it's temperature measured in celsius degrees with 568 distinct values, so I think ties are really issue in my case. Could you please post an answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your data are measured with resolution 0.1 and that the range is at least 18.7. My guess given the mention of "weather" is that they are Celsius temperatures.

Let's guess that the variable has a range 50 in those units: the tails beyond the quartiles are often longer than the difference between the quartiles. That would mean of the order of 500 distinct values.

It seems that your sample size is of the order of 500000, so on average each distinct value occurs about 1000 times, and ties are everywhere.

It's also entirely possible that your data are quirkier than that if human readings are involved. Many observers use some final digits rather than others, although the quirks can vary, including preferences for 0 and 5 as final digits or for even digits.

Ties are likely to be the issue, together with a rule that the same values must be assigned to the same bin.